# PHP Regex to match an IP address

Tags: php, regex

On PHP
question: 
From string "192.168.0.23, 192.168.2.33, 124.125.126.127" remove IP address ", 124.125.126.127".
leave only: "192.168.0.23, 192.168.2.33"

Thank you.

Comment: Very "smart" way to do your homework

Comment: `$string = "192.168.0.23, 192.168.2.33";` will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex: `/[\w.]{15}/` and replace with nothing or empty string `""`.

```
<?php
$string = '192.168.0.23, 192.168.2.33, 124.125.126.127';
$pattern = '/[\d.]{15}/';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Then, remove the last comma with some native php string function. (*I don't know much about php*)

Demo: http://ideone.com/xNCVNC

Comment: `abc.def.hij.klm` matches your regexp.

Answer (score 0):

#### A regex free solution

```
<?php
$str='192.168.0.23, 192.168.2.33, 124.125.126.192';
print_r(array_filter(explode(', ',$str),function ($v){  return substr($v,0,3)=='192'?$v:''; }));
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/131859)

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 192.168.0.23
    [1] => 192.168.2.33
)
```